# How to specify input format in SQL create table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I'm new in SQL and I need to create table with specified field format. How to add CHECK condition that will assure that input will be formatted e.g.

[LLLDD]

where L is a letter and D is a digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3974b

```
create table test (
  field1 char(5),
  check (field1 like '[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9]')
);

insert into test values ('ttt09'); --this will succeed
```

If you were to change the insert to:

```
insert into test values ('testi'); -- this will fail
insert into test values ('12345'); -- this will fail
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you are adding the constraint on a new table

```
CONSTRAINT ck_data_checker CHECK ([columnName] LIKE ('[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]'))
```

Try this if you are adding the constraint on existing table

```
  ALTER TABLE tableName
  ADD CONSTRAINT ck_data_checker CHECK ([columnName] LIKE ('[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sql server expert, but I think you can add a LIKE with a regular expression. Have a look at these websites

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc127433-2982-4065-b290-f411a075a694/use-regular-expressions-to-check-sql-server-2012-table-fields?forum=databasedesign